# is there a way to flush a whole zone's rich rules on firewalld?

Tags: firewalld, firewall-cmd

I have added many rich rule with something like this:

```
 firewall-cmd --permanent --zone="thezone" --add-rich-rule='rule family=ipv4 source address=1.2.3.4 reject'
```

And now I would like to clear/remove all those rich rules in my "thezone" zone.

Also y try to remove line for line with :

```
 firewall-cmd --permanent --zone="thezone" --remove-rich-rule='rule family=ipv4 source address=1.2.3.4 reject'
```

or

```
 firewall-cmd --permanent --zone="thezone" --remove-rich-rule='rule family=ipv4 source address=1.2.3.4 accept'
```

or

```
 firewall-cmd --permanent --zone="thezone" --add-rich-rule='rule family=ipv4 source address=1.2.3.4 accept'
```

with the firewall-cmd --reload and still haven't succeed.

Can Anyone tell me how to clear all or tell what i'm doing wrong with one by one method?

Comment: for those who did not know theres is a xml file in /etc/firewalld/zones with the name of the zone like: the zone.xml and you can edit/remove rules there.

Answer (score 4):

Empty the contents of (or remove):

- /etc/firewalld/zones/**zone**.xml
- /etc/firewalld/zones/**zone**.xml.old

Note: where **zone** is the name of the zone you need to remove.

Then restart the firewalld service

Comment: This is the correct answer and is similar to @Mik who posted a comment on their own question.

The filename in question might differ, for example, on my system it's `public.xml` and `public.xml.old`. I run Virtualmin / Webmin.